# HTML font size too small when switching to Middle-East Languages

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have a multi-language Web application that is due to support all languages. My current problem is that when Middle-East languages are being displayed (e.g. Arabic, Persian, Hebrew, etc.) the font is much smaller than when showing Western languages.

The application is developed using Angular and hence the font is globally declared once as `<font face="verdana">`. Of course, there are places where I change the size of the font but, consistently, everywhere it is shown much smaller than the westerns.

Is there any simple way I could have all languages shown with the same size?

I'm if course willing to switch to a different font if required.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Languages are assigned a class and "subtag" automatically that you can use to style individual languages.

For example, in your case you would set your css to be,

```css
body   {font-family: "Times New Roman",serif;}
    :lang(en)  {font-family: "Scheherazade",serif; 
                 font-size: 190%;}
    :lang(ar)  {font-family: "Scheherazade",serif; 
                 font-size: 120%;}
```

```html
<div id="main">
          <ul>
              <li class="top_btn_class mr2e"><a href="j/index.html">日本語</a></li>
              <li class="top_btn_class"><a href="e/index.html"><span lang="en">English</span></a></li>
            <li class="top_btn_class"><a href="e/index.html"><span lang="ar">الأَبْجَدِيَّ</span></a></li>
          </ul>
         </div>
        <!-- /#main --></div>
```

Here is a link to all the language subtags. http://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry/language-subtag-registry (**WARNING:** Big list, could take a bit to load)

Comment: Hello @Atom and thanks for your quick response. Still, two points: (1) I clicked on **Run code snippet** and got the rendering of your code. If you try it, you will see that still Japanese and Arabic are smaller that English. (2) I'm not a big expert (as yet, and perhaps never...), so it would be very useful for me if you could provide detailed instructions on how to use your suggestion (I'm guessing that you are telling the browser to increase fonts by 20% and 90%, but don't quite know how and where to do it).